# Can Data Alerts in the Power BI service send out multiple emails?

Tags: powerbi

This is what we would like to do regarding data alerts in the PBI service. We have a data set containing our company's financial chart of accounts and other financial data.

On each refresh of data, we will calculate a certain value for some of these accounts. ***For each account*** where the value falls outside a certain threshold, we would like to send an email to one or more people notifying them of this situation along with the account in question.

After a refresh, we might have zero accounts having a value falling outside the threshold, or we might have dozens. If we have dozens, we would want to send an email to one or more people for each of the accounts.

In addition to the emails, we might want to call a Microsoft Power App application for each account having a value falling outside the threshold.

Having read the documentation on data alerts in the PBI service, it's not clear to me if we would be able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a single alert currently doesn't have enough customizability to output multiple values for multiple accounts (unless perhaps you set up a fancy measure that maps the N-dimensional vector of accounts to a single dimension to do such a thing indirectly).

If you're willing to set up separate alerts for separate accounts, then you should be able to define an [alert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-set-data-alerts) for each one and hook that up to a Power Automate flow like [this one](https://us.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/37949735968746efa0defc14af94ab06/send-an-e-mail-to-any-audience-when-a-power-bi-data-alert-is-triggered/).
This process is described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-flow-integration

Comment: Thanks Alexis. This is pretty much what I thought. I briefly considered setting up separate alerts for each account but that would be a maintenance nightmare since there could be 100+ accounts and accounts come and go.